# My variable loses its value in javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My code :

```
  function func()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:someurl ,
            type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {foo},
        success: function (response) {
            var Myvariable= [[]];         
      
          $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: anotherUrl,
                data: {
                 bar
                },
                success: function (result) {

             
                 

                    Myvariable= result.data;
                  console.log(Myvariable);
               //in this line Myvariable show expected result **
                    
                }
            });

      
            console.log(Myvariable);
          // but in this line it has no value ++

        }
    });
    }
```

in line ** Myvariable has a value I expected
which is array below

> [[2,2],[4/5,4/5],[3,3],[0/5,0/5],[2,2],[4/5,4/5],[3,3],[4/5,4/5],[2,2],[4/5,4/5],[3,3],[4/5,4/5],[2,2],[4/5,4/5]]

but in line ++ it loses its value. Please help me find the reason.

Comment: It's happening because these ajax calls are asynchronous in nature, so after you got your first ajax call success it will call another ajax call, but it will continue executing. So as second ajax call will take time meanwhile it will print console.log written at the end. That is why you are not getting data at the end.

Comment: can you try to make Myvariable as global and see if it work.

Comment: It didnt _lose_ a value. It just didnt get the value yet

Comment: You can also use Promise or async/await to fix this issue.